# CodeIgniter ajax call using jquery when call redirect it prints the whole page i div

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter, redirect

no title that fits this bug but this how it goes, i have form with a submit button when pressed jquery ajax calls the controller and the form validation is done if it fails the form is redrawn if it passes the page is redirected to the home page with flash message successes and thats where the bug happens it redraws the whole page in the content(header header footer footer). i hope it makes sense seeing is believing so here is the code

side notes: "autform" is a lib for creating forms "rest" is a lib for templates.

the jquery code:

```
$("form.user_form").live("submit",function() {
  $("#loader").removeClass('hidden');
  $.ajax({
      async :false,
      type: $(this).attr('method'),
      url: $(this).attr('action'),
      cache: false,
      data: $(this).serialize(),
      success: function(data) {
                $("#center").html(data);
                     $('div#notification').hide().slideDown('slow').delay(20000).slideUp('slow');
                }
  })

  return false;
 });
```

the controller

```
 function forgot_password()
{
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('login',lang('email_or_login'), 'trim|required|xss_clean');
        $this->autoform->add(array('name'=>'login', 'type'=>'text', 'label'=> lang('email_or_login')));
        $data['errors'] = array();
        if ($this->form_validation->run($this)) {                               // validation ok
            if (!is_null($data = $this->auth->forgot_password(
                    $this->form_validation->set_value('login')))) {
                    $this-> _show_message(lang('auth_message_new_password_sent'));
            } else {
                $data['message']=$this-> _message(lang('error_found'), false);  // fail
                $errors = $this->auth->get_error_message();
                foreach ($errors as $k => $v){
                     $this->autoform->set_error($k, lang($v));
                }
            }
        }
        $this->autoform->add(array('name'=>'forgot_button', 'type'=>'submit','value' =>lang('new_password')));
        $data['form']=  $this->autoform->generate('','class="user_form"');
        $this->set_page('forms/default', $data);
        if ( !$this->input->is_ajax_request()) { $this->rest->setPage(''); }
        else { echo  $this->rest->setPage_ajax('content');       }
    }
}

function _show_message($message, $state = true)
{
    if($state)
    {
        $data = '<div id="notification" class="success"><strong>'.$message.'</strong></div>';
    }else{
        $data = '<div id="notification" class="bug"><strong>'.$message.'</strong></div>';
    }
    $this->session->set_flashdata('note', $data);
    redirect(base_url(),'refresh');
}
```

i think it as if the redirect call is caught by ajax and instead of sending me the home page it loads the home page  in the place of the form.

thanks for any help 
regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK found the problem and solution, it seemed you cant call a redirect in the middle of an Ajax call that is trying to return a chunk of HTML to a div, the result will be placing the redirected HTML in the div.

The solution as suggested by   **PhilTem** at http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/210403/ 
is when you want to redirect and the call is made by Ajax then return a value with the redirect URI back to Ajax and let it redirect instead.

For anyone interested in the code:

The **Jquery** Ajax code:

```
$("form.user_form").live("submit", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $("#loader").removeClass('hidden');
  $.ajax({
      type: $(this).attr('method'),
      url: $(this).attr('action'),
      cache: false,
      dataType:"html",
      data: $(this).serialize(),
      success: function(data) {
          var res = $(data).filter('span.redirect');
          if ($(res).html() != null) {
              [removed].href=$(res).html();
              return false;
          }
          $("#center").html(data);
      },
      error: function() {

      }
  })
  return false;
});
```

The **PHP** Controller

```
function _show_message($message, $state = true, $redirect = '')
{
    if ($state)
    {
        $data = '<div id="notification" class="success"><strong>'.$message.'</strong></div>';
    } else {
        $data = '<div id="notification" class="bug"><strong>'.$message.'</strong></div>';
    }

    $this->session->set_flashdata('note', $data);

    if ( !$this->input->is_ajax_request())
    {
        redirect(base_url() . $redirect, 'location', 302);
    }
    else
    {
         echo '<span class="redirect">'.base_url().$redirect.'</span>';
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

just use individual errors

```
json_encode(array(
   'fieldname'  =>  form_error('fieldname')
));
```

AJAX

```
success: function(cb)
{
    if(fieldname)
    {
       {fieldname}.after(cb.fieldname)
    }
}
```

see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9108670/ajax-form-responce-handling-objectloop)

Comment: i am sending chuncks of html back to the form it helps keep the code short, and i use one jquery function to for all my forms.